# Alamofire multiple request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have `tableView` and I use `Alamofire` to send and get request from server.
as you can see in picture, in my `tableView` I send multiple request in table's header and `cell` at index 0,1. if I send my request in one function it will too long to get response and can't control error for each request. what is best way to handle this problem?

[image]
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create **one request**.

So by parsing your request you should **set up your data source into an array**, so **each row** will get the data **from a single item** of that array.

Then you would update your table view with this data source.

For instance:

1) **Create a variable** for data source (outside of methods):

```
var source : [Something]
```

2) **Request all** in a single request

```
Alamofire.request(_,_,_)
.responseJSON {
   // create a data source
   // this request should be a merge of your three request stated in your question
   // source can be set as [Something] for instance
}
```

3) In your **cellForRow** delegate **method** you should do something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( ... 
   dataForARow = self.source[indexPath.row]
   cell.label.text = dataForARow["name"] //etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple requests is fine just display your table cell OR header based on the response of each request.

Until you didn't receive response for any request set height to 0 for that particular cell or header.